# Django urls.py deprecated, urlpatterns to change

Tags: python, django

I try to compile an old code in Django 1.4
Many things are deprecated. I manage to change some of them but I don't knwo how to go futher on the urls.py

here is the old code

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

dynurls = patterns('minesweepr.views',
    (r'^api/minesweeper_solve/$', 'api_solve'),
)

staticurls = patterns('minesweepr.views',
    (r'^player/$', 'template_static'),
    (r'^query/$', 'template_static'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^%s' % settings.BASE_URL, include(dynurls)),
    ('^%s' % settings.BASE_STATIC_URL, include(staticurls)),            
)
```

I know django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated and I tried to change the code like this

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings

dynurls = ['minesweepr.views',
    (r'^api/minesweeper_solve/$', 'api_solve'),
]

staticurls = ['minesweepr.views',
    (r'^player/$', 'template_static'),
    (r'^query/$', 'template_static'),
]

urlpatterns = ['',
    ('^%s' % settings.BASE_URL, include(dynurls)),
    ('^%s' % settings.BASE_STATIC_URL, include(staticurls)),            
]
```

But it is not sufficient
It is said my url patterns are invalid. 
Anybody has an idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Django 1.4 is many years old at this point, and hasn't been supported in a very long time. I would recommend taking a few days, and upgrading it one version at a time. Django 1.5 introduced so very big changes with custom user models, but other than that, migrating should be a fairly straight forward process if you read the release notes for each version along the way.

Start by going to version 1.5 with these release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.5/

Then on to 1.6, 1.7 with migrations, and so on. That'll be your best path to get current.

The URLs changes you're referring to were majorly changed in version 2.0, but I would highly recommend taking the step-by-step approach.